# Mongodb slice array projection returns other fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-nodejs-driver

In my data, one of the fields is an array and I want to return only a section of that array, and only that, no more fields. But when I'm using the `$slice` in projection, it will return all the fields.

My data:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "641eca0f5687d0937c1041e2"
  },
  "email": "example@gmail.com",
  "password": "$2b$10$MBuDAi3k7jTvckTsqQliQeWeg18JebLaDdltzMJwJ92bwP7i84Ee2",
  "emailVerified": true,
  "transactions": [
    {
      "category": "t2",
      "subCategory": "bread",
      "type": "expense",
      "date": "2023-03-25T16:53:59.779Z",
      "amount": "1000",
      "id": {
        "$oid": "641f2727dc59db57eac9fa29"
      }
    },
    {
      "category": "t3",
      "subCategory": "bread",
      "type": "expense",
      "date": "2023-03-25T16:54:04.243Z",
      "amount": "1000",
      "id": {
        "$oid": "641f272cdc59db57eac9fa2a"
      }
    },
    {
      "category": "t4",
      "subCategory": "bread",
      "type": "expense",
      "date": "2023-03-25T16:54:08.780Z",
      "amount": "1000",
      "id": {
        "$oid": "641f2730dc59db57eac9fa2b"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And my query in node.js is like this:

```
const result = await users.findOne(
  { _id: new ObjectId(id) },
  { projection: { transactions: { $slice: [1, 2] } }}
);
```

With this projection, I'm getting all the fields in the result. If I change the projection to something like `{ transactions: { $slice: [1, 2] }, _id: 1 }`, it will return only the `transactions` and `_id`. But I only want the transactions.

**Update:**

After some research, I found that this is possible with `aggregate` method. What aggregate is doing, is basically recreating the projection based on previous stage on the pipeline. But still, I don't know about the `projection` on `findOne` method.

```js
const aggCursor = users.aggregate<TransactionsPagRes>([
  {
    $match: { _id: new ObjectId(id) },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      transactions: { $slice: ['$transactions', 1, 2] },
    },
  },
]);

const result = await aggCursor.next();
```

Comment: `_id: 0` in the projection instead of `1`?

Comment: @user20042973 No, that doesn't work. It returns everything too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with `transactions` being returned, you need to blacklist other properties you don't need like this:

```js
db.collection.find({},
{
  transactions: {
    $slice: [
      1,
      2
    ]
  },
  _id: 0,
  email: 0,
  password: 0,
  emailVerified: 0
})
```

It will return info as:

```json
[
  {
    "transactions": [
      {
        "amount": "1000",
        "category": "t3",
        "date": "2023-03-25T16:54:04.243Z",
        "id": ObjectId("641f272cdc59db57eac9fa2a"),
        "subCategory": "bread",
        "type": "expense"
      },
      {
        "amount": "1000",
        "category": "t4",
        "date": "2023-03-25T16:54:08.780Z",
        "id": ObjectId("641f2730dc59db57eac9fa2b"),
        "subCategory": "bread",
        "type": "expense"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If you want to have a flat array of user's transactions, aggregation with [$unwind](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is a way to go:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "641eca0f5687d0937c1041e2"
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      transactions: {
        $slice: [
          "$transactions",
          1,
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$transactions"
  }
])
```

Returns:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "641eca0f5687d0937c1041e2",
    "transactions": {
      "amount": "1000",
      "category": "t3",
      "date": "2023-03-25T16:54:04.243Z",
      "id": ObjectId("641f272cdc59db57eac9fa2a"),
      "subCategory": "bread",
      "type": "expense"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "641eca0f5687d0937c1041e2",
    "transactions": {
      "amount": "1000",
      "category": "t4",
      "date": "2023-03-25T16:54:08.780Z",
      "id": ObjectId("641f2730dc59db57eac9fa2b"),
      "subCategory": "bread",
      "type": "expense"
    }
  }
]
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yBcbesVy_2S).

Comment: The first method seems unintuitive, it's possible obviously, but I don't think that's the answer. I have also done this with `aggregate` function without the `$unwind`, it actually works as expected (unlike the `findOne` `projection`). I'll share it in the original post. I was hoping if there is a way to do it with `findOne`. But I guess I go with `aggregate` for now. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `$slice` operator does not appear to exclude other fields like a projection normally would,  this seems to be unexpected behavior in MongoDB.

A couple of choices to get the behavior you want:

1. modify the projection passed to the find
   Since an projection will never implicitly exclude _id, you will need to modify this anyway.  To exclude all of the other fields, either explicitly exclude every field, or include a field that does not actually exist.

```
const result = await users.findOne(
  { _id: new ObjectId(id) },
  { projection: { 
     _id:0,
     _not_a_real_field: 1,
     transactions: { $slice: [1, 2] } 
  }}
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SC48Xf_rcID)

2. use an aggregation pipeline
   You will still need to explicitly exclude the _id, but would not need to reference a non-existent field to exclude the others

```
[
  {$match: {_id: ObjectId("641eca0f5687d0937c1041e2")}}},
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      transactions: {$slice: ["$transactions",1,2]}
  }}
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S5_t7nBwBHu)

Answer (score 0):

### Counterintuitive MongoDB

I've accidentally found seemingly [unrelated bit](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#behavior) in MongoDB documentation, with just one important sentence:

> The $slice projection by itself is considered an exclusion.

It seems like Mongo considers `$slice` to be an exclusion of fields, not
inclusion. That is, this projection:

```
{ transactions: { $slice: [1, 2] } }
```

**does not** return just `transaction` field with two elements, it returns **all the fields in the document, with `transaction` modified to contain only two elements**

If you include any other fields together with `$slice`, the projection will return that field and sliced array, as expected:

```
{ _id: true, transactions: { $slice: [1, 2] } }
```

I've observed this behavior not just in Mongoose, but in `mongosh` as well

### Example

Let's say you have the following model:

```js
const User = model('User', new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String
  favoriteColors: [String]
}))
```

And a single document in the DB (object id is replaced with number for brevity)

```js
{ 
  _id: 0, 
  firstName: 'Bob', 
  lastName: 'Bobski', 
  favoriteColors: ['blue', 'orange'] 
}
```

Here is unexpected result of projection with single `$slice`:

```js
const results = await User.find({}, { 
  favoriteColors: { $slice: [1, 1] } 
})

// results is [{ _id: 0, firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Bobski', favoriteColors: ['blue'] }]
// Note that `favoriteColors` is sliced, but all others fields are returned too
```

Once you add the other field, result is expected:

```js
const results = await User.find({}, { 
  _id: true, 
  favoriteColors: { $slice: [1, 1] } 
})

// results is [{ _id: 0, favoriteColors: ['blue'] }]
```

As suggested by the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75859339/12983861), excluding non-existent field works too:

```js
const results = await User.find({}, { 
  _id: false, 
  notARealField: true, 
  favoriteColors: { $slice: [1, 1] } 
})

// results is [{ favoriteColors: ['blue'] }]
```